# How to extend ExtJs component?

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to extend a Ext.from.FormPanel that it comprises Grid and some buttons. I found Saki's example:

```
Ext.ns('MyApp');

MyApp.AbstractFormPanel = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
 defaultType:'textfield'
,frame:true
,width:300
,height:200
,labelWidth:75
,submitUrl:null
,submitT:'Submit'
,cancelT:'Cancel'
,initComponent:function() {

    // create config object
    var config = {
        defaults:{anchor:'-10'}
    };

    // build config
    this.buildConfig(config);

    // apply config
    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));

    // call parent
    MyApp.AbstractFormPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

} // eo function initComponent

,buildConfig:function(config) {
    this.buildButtons(config);
} // eo function buildConfig

,buildButtons:function(config) {
    config.buttons = [{
         text:this.submitT
        ,scope:this
        ,handler:this.onSubmit
        ,iconCls:'icon-disk'
    },{
         text:this.cancelT
        ,scope:this
        ,handler:this.onCancel
        ,iconCls:'icon-undo'
    }];
}

,onSubmit:function() {
    Ext.MessageBox.alert('Submit', this.submitUrl);
} 

,onCancel:function() {
    this.el.mask('This form is canceled');
} // eo function onCancel

}); // eo extend
```

it may contain as many buttons as I'll give it. But how to add Grid? I gonna put grid in `initConmponent` like this?

```
initComponent:function() {

    // create config object
    var config = {
        defaults:{anchor:'-10'}
    };

    // build config
    this.buildConfig(config);

    // apply config
    Ext.apply(this, Ext.apply(this.initialConfig, config));

    // call parent
    MyApp.AbstractFormPanel.superclass.initComponent.call(this);

   mygrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({....});

}
```

Where i can found good example or tutorial?
PS: ExtJs version 3.4.

Comment: What ExtJS version do you use ?

Answer (score 0):

The grid fits into the form container in the items block.
Saki has an [example](http://examples.extjs.eu/) of a grid in a window. http://examples.extjs.eu/one2many.html 
In it you can see that the window component has items array. and the grid is an item in that array.

What you need to do is have your form panel declare items array where one of the items is the grid.